# Using ghost.py to change the value of a select dropdown and retrieve values after update

Tags: python, html-parsing, screen-scraping, web-scraping, ghost.py

Default action for the webpage is to list results by relevance but has a dropdown box that can be used to change the results table sort order. I would like to use Ghost.py to mimic the action of changing the dropdown box from relevance to post date.

HTML for the dropdown select box:

```
<select name="MMM_ddlSortOrder" id="MMM_ddlSortOrder" onchange="SortSearch('MMM_ddlSortOrder');">
   <option value='RELEVANCE:D">Best Match</option>
   <option value='POSTDATE:D">Date Posted: Newest First</option>
   <option value='POSTDATE:A">Date Posted: Oldest First</option>
</select>
```

my.py:

```
from ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost()
page, resources = ghost.open('http://localhost.com/index.html')
result, resources = ghost.evaluate("document.getElementbyId('MMM_ddlSortOrder').getAttribute('POSTDATE:D');")
```

I think the problem is with my ghost.evaluate paramaeters, would should they be? And do I have to "fire" the javascript function after the eval before calling ghost.content?

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I want it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

```
from ghost import Ghost 
ghost = Ghost()
ghost.fill("form",{'MMM_ddlSortOrder':'POSTDATE:D'})
ghost.evaluate( "document.getElementById('MMM_ddlSortOrder').setAttribute('POSTDATE:D');")
```